# Let $X$ be symmetrically distributed about 0. Show that $X$ and -$X$ are identically distributed

Tags: probability, statistics

Hello Mathematicians!

The definition of being symmetrically distributed about zero means that the PDF (Continuous) or PMF (Discrete) $f(x) = f(-x)$. And the definition of being identically distributed is $$P(X \in A) = P(Y \in A)$$ for every $A \in \beta$, where $\beta$ is a sigma field.

Actually, I don't see what to prove, because  Could you give any idea?

Comment: Actually the DEFINITION of $X$ being symetrically distributed is that $X$ and $-X$ are identically distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general setup, via the chamge of formula in the integral and then the symetry of the distribution:
$$
P(X\in A) = \int_A P_X(dx) = \int_{-A} P_X(-dy) = \int_{-A} P_X(+dy) = P(X\in -A)
$$